# How does iterative reweighted least squares actually produce estimates that maximise likelihood?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, optimization

From the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares), we see that:

> IRLS is used to find the maximum likelihood estimates of a generalized linear model, ...

However, they describe the algorithm as an iterated algorithm that minimises objective functions of the following form:

$$\underset{\boldsymbol\beta} {\operatorname{arg\,min}} \sum_{i=1}^n \big| y_i - f_i (\boldsymbol\beta) \big|^p$$

This does not look like a minimiser for the log-likelihood $\ell(\mathbf{y}|\theta)$.